# Windows Phone 8.1 - Bad performance when trying to get Thumbnail images from Camera Roll

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I'm building a Windows Phone 8.1 app (Windows Runtime, not Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1). In my app, I need to display all photos of CameraRoll in a GridView, but as Thumbnails, to reduce memory usage. When I try my app, everything works fine, but it's EXTREMELY slowly.

My code is as follows:

```
===================== MainPage.xaml.cs=============================
var files = await KnownFolders.CameraRoll.GetFilesAsync();
List<ImageSource> imageSources = new List<ImageSource>();

for(int i=0; i<files.Count; i++)
{
    await ExecuteCode(i, files, KnownFolders.CameraRoll, imageSources);
}

photosGrid.DataContext = imageSources;

private async Task ExecuteCode(int index, IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files, StorageFolder folder, List<ImageSource> imageSources)
    {
        uint requestedSize = 90;

            using(StorageItemThumbnail itemThumbnail = await files[index].GetThumbnailAsync(ThumbnailMode.PicturesView, requestedSize))
            {
                using(IRandomAccessStream fStream = itemThumbnail.AsStreamForRead().AsRandomAccessStream())
                {
                    BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                    await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(fStream);

                    imageSources.Add(bitmapImage);

                    bitmapImage = null;
                    GC.AddMemoryPressure((long)itemThumbnail.Size);
                }
            }
    }

========================MainPage.xaml==========================
<GridView x:Name="photosGrid" Height="392" Width="400" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="0,0,-0.333,0" SelectionMode="Multiple" Background="Black">
                        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Image Width="90" Height="90" Margin="5" Source="{Binding}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridView.ItemTemplate>

                        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <ItemsStackPanel />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                    </GridView>
```

Comment: Anybody got an answer for this? I'm also trying to create a gallery viewer but if I fetch more than 100 photos from a folder the App crashes with System.OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: What happens if you remove the AddMemoryPressure call. I am not sure you need to be doing that. The documentation for the AddMemoryPressure command states you need to remove exactly the same amount of pressure when it is not required. System performance is affected if you don't.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.addmemorypressure%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: What about loading the images into Bitmaps directly from the path? Then you can use DecodePixel Width and Height to constraint them. Also, if user sees only portion of them, don't load all the pictures all at once.

Comment: Try to use parallel method, check out this article.[Parallel method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30547103/how-to-improve-performance-method-getthumbnailasync-in-window-phone-8-1)

Answer (score 0):

StorageFile.GetThumbnailAsync(ThumbnailMode) | getThumbnailAsync(ThumbnailMode) method
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br227212.aspx